# Cannot Create New Virtualenv in Lion

Tags: virtualenv, osx-lion, pip

I'm having trouble with virtualenv in Lion. I've clean reinstalled Virtualenv and Pip it but it seems like it's struggling with finding Pip when creating a new environment. I removed virtualenvwrapper to make sure that's not interfering too.

Unfortunately the path it's looking in seems to be truncated in the error message.

The environment gets part created but there's no activate script. This is the traceback:

```
Apollos-Mac-mini:~ apollo$ virtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip.............
  Complete output from command /Users/apollo/test/bin/python /Users/apollo/test/bin/easy_install /Library/Python/2.7/...ort/pip-1.0.2.tar.gz:
  Processing pip-1.0.2.tar.gz
Running pip-1.0.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/61/08st3n995qn_w6rsjqgv1cx00000gn/T/easy_install-Za9IA8/pip-1.0.2/egg-dist-tmp-lyVJEQ
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

error: byte-compiling is disabled.
----------------------------------------
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.6.4', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 810, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 912, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 648, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 878, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/apollo/test/bin/python /Users/apollo/test/bin/easy_install /Library/Python/2.7/...ort/pip-1.0.2.tar.gz failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Can you execute /Users/apollo/test/bin/python /Users/apollo/test/bin/easy_install /Library/Python/2.7/...ort/pip-1.0.2.tar.gz manually?

Comment: I can execute the created environment's python and easy_install, yes. I found that the search path is supposed to be `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support` so I downloaded `pip-1.0.2.tar.gz` into there and ran `/Users/apollo/test/bin/easy_install /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.0.2.tar.gz`. It ultimately gave the error `error: byte-compiling is disabled.`

Comment: OK! The problem is that I have `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` in my `.profile` -- I don't seem to be able to answer my own question so I'm putting this here.

Comment: Tim: you can answer for your own question in 24h. Please answer and I'll upvote you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim: you are probably right from what I can see from this link - https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/168/easy_install-fails-with-byte-compiling

There's another interesting note at the end of the link which you might want to check out. It says 
"Setting export VIRTUALENV_USE_DISTRIBUTE=1 fixed the problem."

I would recommend that you use distribute to install your packages as it seems to give me a lot less trouble than the traditional setuptools. Using the **--distribute** option like this:-

```
# Not using distribute, uses setuptools
$ virtualenv test1
New python executable in test1/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.

# Using distribute by specifying the option
$ virtualenv --distribute test2 
New python executable in test2/bin/python
Installing distribute.....................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip...............done.
```

In any case, glad you solved your own question! :-)

Comment: Considering this most correct as it allows me to continue to disable byte compiling.

Comment: nice! glad to learn about a little more about PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE too. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with `easy_install` not working when you disable byte compiling (.pyc files) in Python. I did this on my development machine because I persistently struggled with bugs due to .pyc files being used when I'd deleted the original .py.

To correct this I removed

```
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

from `~/.profile`.

calvinx's answer also solves this by using distribute instead of easy_install. I suppose both answers could be considered correct but calvinx's allows you to continue disabling byte compiling so I'll mark that as correct.

Comment: Sorry this is such a noob question... but how do you find and open `~/.profile`?

Comment: Sure. Open a terminal and type `vim ~/.profile` or `mate ~/.profile` respectivly to open in Vim or Textmate.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it just removing all the .pyc files